# Insert array from form to sql

Tags: php, mysql

I have a form that someone can add multiple phone numbers and extension, and I am trying to save them in the database, whenever I save the data it shows the word "Array" in both filed.

Here is my code so far:

```
if (!empty($_POST['Phone']) && isset($_POST['Extension'])) {
foreach ($_POST['Phone'] as $key => $value) {
    foreach ($_POST['Extension'] as $key => $value2) {
        $para = array("UserID" => \PDO::PARAM_INT, "Phone" => \PDO::PARAM_STR, "Extension" => \PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $val = array($_SESSION['UserID'], $_POST['Phone'], $_POST['Extension']);
        $r = DB::Call("[spPhoneInsert]", $para, $val);           
    }
}

if (count($r) > 0 && $r[0]['Result'] == 'Ok') {
    header("location:home.php?added_phone=1");
} else {
    header("location:home.php?error_phone=1");
}
exit;
}
```

Comment: What problem you are facing in it ?

Comment: whenever, I post the data from the table the result show as Array not the real values I posted

Comment: why are you looping extension inside phone's loop, do you have multiple extensions for each phone or something?

Comment: each phone have one extension

Answer (score 1):

whenever you post a form with multiple same name elements like

```
<input type="text" name="phone[]">
<input type="text" name="phone[]">
```

data is posted as array to the action page.
You have to loop through this array to save them in data base

you can loop like this and create whatever format you want
Following code will save your number and extension comma seprated

```
    foreach ($_POST['phone'] as $number){
    $allNumbers .= $number.',';
    }
foreach ($_POST['extension'] as $ext){
    $allExt .= $ext.',';
    }
  $para = array("UserID" => \PDO::PARAM_INT, "Phone" => \PDO::PARAM_STR, "Extension" => \PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $val = array($_SESSION['UserID'], trim($allNumbers,','), trim($allExt,','));
        $r = DB::Call("[spPhoneInsert]", $para, $val);
```

Comment: I already have the my input like this `<input type="text" name="Phone[]">`

Comment: thats right but on action page you your $_POST['phone'] is available as array thats why it is insert as array in your column

Comment: The result of inserting data in the form shows the word "Array" and I want to view the data inserted. how can I change it to insert the data i submited in the form, and not show me the word array

Comment: when I echo it, it will show the inserted data, but its not going to the database

Comment: I tried to add two arrays by using the code. the first one was added but the value was empty in the database, and the second one wasn't added